# Javascript: need clarification about a particular type of variable declaration

Tags: javascript

I've just started out with Javascript and I'm coming across declarations of the following type quite often:
`var var_name = window.var_name = window.var_name || {};`
Can someone explain what is the significance of such a declaration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This expression:

```
window.var_name || {}
```

...simply returns the value of `window.var_name` unless that value is falsy (`false`, `0`, `''`, `undefined`, `null`, or `NaN`), in which case it evaluates to an empty object (`{}`). This is used to provide a default value when `window.var_name` does not exist.

The resulting value is then assigned back to `window.var_name`:

```
window.var_name = window.var_name || {};
```

Which is then assigned to a (possibly) new variable named `var_name`:

```
var var_name = window.var_name = window.var_name || {};
```

In the global scope `var_name` is equal to `window.var_name`. Inside a function, `var_name` will refer to a new local variable.

Answer (score 0):

`var_name` is a global scope variable initialized to the browser's window `var_name` value. if there is no value, it is initialized as an empty object, `{}`. just a copy of the window var_name for localized usage.

Answer (score 0):

`window.var_name || {}` equates to `window.var_name` if it is set, or the empty object otherwise.

The rest of the statement simply devines the variables `var_name` and `window.var_name` to that value